# MySQL Join v. Subquery to get a conditional date while optimizing performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, subquery

I need your help on deciding which query to use since we are facing performance issue with MySQL  joins and Subqueries.

The problem is that I'm trying to find out user's 'first order date' while they should fit certain conditions:

```
order_status = 1(completed) or order_status = 2(canceled)
```

The Tables are tb_order and tb_user; All the columns that contain a 'time' are using Unix Time Stamp.

The result I need looks like this:

| order_id | user_id | user_1st_order_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 47 | 1666876594 |
| 2 | 982 | 1667095997 |

**Option 1: JOIN**

```
Select
    o.id as 'order_id',
    u.id as 'user_id',
    ox.create_time as 'user_1st_order_date'
from
    tb_order o
    left join tb_user u on o.user_id = u.id
    /* here I have about 10 joins */

    left join
    (
        select
            ux.id,
            ox.create_time
        from
            tb_user u
            left join tb_order ox on ox.user_id = u.id
        where
            ( ox.order_status = 1 or ox.order_status = 2 ) 
            /* Orders can be (completed) or (canceled)  */
        group by
            ux.id
    ) x on x.id = u.id 

    /*  The thought here is by using group by `ux.id` I will get the 
    user's earliest completed or canceled order and it's `create_time` 
    then this can be used to `join` the order info */

where
    o.create_time != 0
    and
    ( o.order_status = 1 or o.order_status = 2 )

group by
    o.id
```

**Option 2: Subquery**

```
Select 
    o.id as 'order_id', 
    u.id as 'user_id', 
    (
        select
            ox.create_time
        from
            tb_order ox
        where
            (ox.order_status = 1 or ox.order_status = 2) 
            and
            ox.user_id = u.id 
        order by
            ox.id asc 
        limit 1
    ) as 'user_1st_order_date'
from
    tb_order o
    left join tb_user u on o.user_id = u.id 
    /* here I have about 10 joins */

where
    o.create_time != 0
    and
    ( o.order_status = 1 or o.order_status = 2 )

group by
    o.id 

/* Option 1 stopped working somehow yesterday and start to give me the latest order time instead,  and I don't know why. Though I can get the correct date back by putting 'Min()' in front of the ox.create_time */

    left join
    (
        select
            ux.id,
            Min(ox.create_time)
```

Both worked but I'm trying to find the most efficient one since I'll use this on a daily basis to update our data source for Tableau Online.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It should *always* have been Min(ox.create_time).  I don't understand why there was not an error without it.  You must have an aggregate function like min() when you use Group By.

Comment: `1666876594` looks like a date+time, not a date-only value....

Comment: Your "Option 2" is missing a `WHERE` clause at the top: you have an `and` under `from` which isn't legal.

Comment: @Dai Yes 1666876594 is datetime(unix time stamp), but don't worry I can format it to a date easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at query 1, you have set out a crazy set of table relationships.

1. Starting with the Select in parentheses, you have a Left Join that implies there are users without orders. That's OK, but your Where filter is based solely on order status, which is NULL when there is no order, so all such users will be filtered out.  There is no useful purpose being served by joining the tb_user table and it can be omitted from that subquery.
2. In the outer query the Left join of tb_order to tb_user implies there are orders without users, but then joining the subquery using u.id instead of o.userid guarantees that nothing from the subquery will be usable in that case.  Once again, there is no purpose served in bring tb_user in there either.

To get the desired result set you set out above, you can vastly simplify things by looking only at the tb_order table like Option 3 below:

**Option 3**

```
Select * From (
  Select id as 'order_id', user_id as 'user_id'
     ,min(Case When order_status In (1,2) Then create_time End)
           Over (Partition By user_id 
           Between unbounded preceding And unbounded following)
                  AS 'user_1st_order_date'
  From tb_order
)
Where order_status in (1,2)
Order by order_id
```

This can be further simplified by moving the `Where order_status in (1,2)` inside the inner query and removing the Case statement around the created_date, but it's less adaptable to use within other queries.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll post additional info here:
1. The reason I joined tb_user to tb_order is to attach user info from the tb_user table to my order. (e.g. o.id, u.id, u.email, u.phone, etc.)

2. Every order record has a user

3. What I'm trying to get is millions of rows of order data. Each row(order) has order_id, user_id, order_time, and around 30+ other columns. Thus the many "Left Joins".

Hope this elaborates some questions and you are all being much helpful.

Comment: So, just use the Option 3 result set and join it to the tables you want info from, including user table.